# Xcode 14.2: Multiple commands produce

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, yarnpkg

I have added a new library using `yarn add` command. There were no issues after `pod install`. But when i run the app from Xcode v14.2 i get errors as follows.

> Multiple commands produce '/USERS/XX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME_XX/KVAAdNetwork.h'

My system info is as follows.

```
OS: macOS 12.6
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
    Memory: 176.98 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.24.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/npm
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
  IDEs:
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.11 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
    react-native: 0.70.4 => 0.70.4
```

The library that I am trying to add is `react-native-kochava-tracker`.

I looked at the header search paths if there could be duplicate entries. We even tried to follow the Manual linking steps in the documents.

Comment: No i did not. we decided not to use kochava tracker not because of the error but because kochava tracker was not tracking according to our need, even on android.